# sqldf: How to group subcategories based on category

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, group-by, sqldf

I have a csv file with 15 records which has category/Sub category in it.

**Columns: Main_category,Sub_category,Count

 Desired Result: Category,Sub_cat1,50**

I tried it using Python pandas and got the above result:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Main_category','Sub_category']['Sub_category'].count())
```

I am trying to achieve the same using sqldf in R but do not get the count of each sub category for a category. It just displays total count:

```
sqldf("select Main_category, Sub_category, count(*) from MyData group by Main_category")
```

Comment: Please review [mcve]

Comment: Where you have `group by Main_category`, change it to `group by Main_category, Sub_category`

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the mere SQL query, seems like you have to group by both aggregation dimensions, `Main_category` and `Sub_category`, in order the SQL query to even compile in most SQL languages:

```
sqldf("select Main_category, Sub_category, count(*) from MyData group by Main_category, Sub_category")
```